# how to plot google offline Maps apiV3?

Tags: c#, google-maps

Dear All thanks in advance,
I need offline maps support for my desktop application developed in C# windows forms.
Once the map is loaded in the browser, it must retain the map and even if there is no net connection it has to show the navigation.
i am ready to get the license for the maps if it is possible.
please help me in finding the solution.

Comment: is it possible to implement offline maps without license version?

Answer (score 0):

Directions and Navigation require a network connection. See the documentation [here](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/3273567?hl=en). You can however save a map for offline usage (search for a location -> open the info window -> save offline map). Offline maps are very limited in that it may not be available in all area and does not have other features like search. Depending on the level of information you need, maybe you can just take a screenshot of the directions and save that somewhere?

Comment: Thanks andy, for the reply, i searched all over the net but couldn't found any perfect response weather its possible or not.